# Oracle: filter query on datetime

Tags: oracle, datetime, timestamp

I need to restrict a query with a

```
SELECT ... FROM ... 
WHERE my_date=(RESULT FROM A SELECT)
...  ;
```

in order to achieve that I am using as result of the select a timestamp (if I instead use a datetime I get nothing from my select probably because the format I am using trims the datetime at the second).

Sadly this is not working because these kindo of queries:

```
select DISTINCT TO_DATE(TO_TIMESTAMP(TO_DATE('25-10-2017 00:00', 'dd-MM-yyyy HH24:MI'))) from DUAL;
```

return an

ORA-01830: date format picture ends before converting entire input string

how to deal with timestamp to date conversion?

Comment: What is wrong with `CAST(timestamp_col AS DATE)`?  Can you post the full query?

Comment: Thank you Tim, now I got a datetime with the cast( ...as date). So you answered the question. Still I didn't solve my problem which is another question. In fact: 

SELECT * FROM customer WHERE  last_update_dt = CAST( 
(select DISTINCT TO_TIMESTAMP(last_update_dt) from
   ...
) AS DATE);

is returning nothing as if testing the equality between dates were a wrong practice.

Comment: Can you add some data to make this a real question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to just compare and check only he dates use trunc on both LHS and RHS.

```
SELECT ... FROM ... 
WHERE trunc(my_date)=(select trunc(RESULT) FROM A)
...  ;
```

This will just compare the dates by truncating the timestamp values

Answer (score 1):

You can use the combination of "TRUNC" and "IN" keywords in your query to achieve what you are expecting. Please check the below query sample as a reference.

`SELECT * FROM customer WHERE TRUNC(last_update_dt) IN (select DISTINCT (TRUNC(last_update_dt)) from ... )`

Cheers !!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In my specific case the equality is enough so I went for an equality check. Your answer has been of help for me.